# outcome first list in 2 dimensional list

Tags: python

I have a 2 Dimensional list like that :

```
list = [[2, 3, 5], [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [8,9,10],[5,6,7]]
```

I can print the first value of every list with this:

```
[i[0] for i in list]
```

and outcome is:

```
 list = [2, 1, 4, 8, 5]
```

but i want to have outcome like this :

```
list = [[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

my code is this :

```
new_list = [] 
for i in list:
    row = 1
    row_list = list[row]
    new_list.append(row_list)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: On what logic, your desired outcome is `list = [[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. Why the remaining two sublist are not in the outcome?

Comment: @michaelpetronav  beacause i do not need other two remaining  list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can slice your list like this:

```
n = 3 # if you have number of items you need
new_list = list[:n]
```

or:

```
n = 2 # if you have number of items you want to remove
new_list = list[:-n]
```

note that:

> DO NOT use `list` as a name of a variable, list is a built-in in python.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused what are you asking, but if I get i right try

```
print(list[1][1]) #print 2nd element in 2nd subset
print(list[0:3]) #print first 3 elements (in this case subsets) in the list
```

I hope it help.

To remove few object from list, you can use

```
list.remove(something) #remove element from list
```

or to create new list just use

```
l=list[0:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to have outcome like this : list = [[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

This should do it:

```
list_subset = list[:3] # the first 3 elements in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple slicing can be used to skip last two rows like this:

```
list = [[2, 3, 5], [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [8,9,10],[5,6,7]]
print(list[:-2])

[[2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```